# tabindex not working for datepickers

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

The `tab index` on textboxes with the property `Show Date Picker` set to `For Dates` is ignored

Example:

```
Control      Tab
-----------------
Textbox1      1
Datepicker1   2
Datepicker2   3
textbox2      4
```

So it goes from textbox1 to textbox2

Is it normal?

Is there anything to do to make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that there's an option called `Tab Stop`

And it was set to `No` for those two text boxes.

It works like a charm when it's set to `Yes`